Error with ruby installation with version Ruby version >= 3.1.0
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.9. Try installing it with gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.9 and then running the current command again
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 3.1.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

The error message tells you that your current Ruby version (2.6.x) is too old and that the version of activesupport you are trying to install requires at lest Ruby version 3.1.0. I suggest installing a Ruby version manager like rbenv, rvm, or asdf. And then, after installing an up-to-date Ruby version (3.3.x), try are to install the desired activesuport version.
